# Automate backup command not working in job scheduling

Tags: batch-file, backup, postgresql-8.4

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 on my Windows Server 2012 box. I have made a configuration with pgagent for job scheduling. I need to schedule an auto backup on a daily basis on my system using with job scheduling. I searched the net and created a batch file and located the file path in job scheduling.

If I run the batch file on my server then it works fine, but when I call it using scheduling in PostgreSQL then it goes in the running stage, but does not give any kind of result.

Below is the command I used for taking backup:

```
"c:\Program Files (86)\path\to\bin" pg_dump.exe -i -h hostname -U username -F c -b -v -f "backup\file\path\filename.backup" databasename
```

This command is working fine on the command prompt and when calling the batch file, but does not give any output from PostgreSQL job scheduling.

Does anyone have any idea about this kind of issue?

Comment: @jeroen: thanks to improve my question.